# Vendure - How to add many-to-many relation custom field and query it?

Tags: typescript, graphql

My target is to filter Assets by related Product's custom field so I'm trying to add products relation custom field to Asset entity. Unfortunately I didn't find in [docs](https://www.vendure.io/docs/developer-guide/customizing-models/#relations) the proper way to create many-to-many relation. I've added that to vendure-config.ts

```
...
customFields: {
  ...
  Asset: [
    {
      name: "products",
      type: "relation",
      list: true,
      entity: Product,
      eager: false,
    },
  ]
}
```

And after "generate-types" I got that in "generated-admin/shop-types"

```
export type Asset = Node & {
  __typename?: 'Asset';
  id: Scalars['ID'];
  createdAt: Scalars['DateTime'];
  updatedAt: Scalars['DateTime'];
  name: Scalars['String'];
  type: AssetType;
  fileSize: Scalars['Int'];
  mimeType: Scalars['String'];
  width: Scalars['Int'];
  height: Scalars['Int'];
  source: Scalars['String'];
  preview: Scalars['String'];
  focalPoint?: Maybe<Coordinate>;
  customFields?: Maybe<AssetCustomFields>;
};

export type AssetCustomFields = {
  __typename?: 'AssetCustomFields';
  products?: Maybe<Array<Product>>;
};
```

I'm getting error response when try to query assets by asset list query

```
query GetAssetList($options: AssetListOptions) {
  assets(options: $options) {
    items {
      ...Asset
      tags {
        ...Tag
        __typename
      }
      __typename
    }
    totalItems
    __typename
  }
}

fragment Asset on Asset {
  id
  createdAt
  updatedAt
  name
  fileSize
  mimeType
  type
  preview
  source
  width
  height
  focalPoint {
    x
    y
    __typename
  }
  customFields {
    products {
      id
    }
    __typename
  }
  __typename
}

fragment Tag on Tag {
  id
  value
  __typename
}
```

Error response:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "relation \"asset_custom_fields_products_product\" does not exist",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 36,
          "column": 5
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "assets",
        "items",
        0,
        "customFields",
        "products"
      ]
    },
    {
      "message": "relation \"asset_custom_fields_products_product\" does not exist",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 36,
          "column": 5
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "assets",
        "items",
        10,
        "customFields",
        "products"
      ]
    },
    ...
}
```